# Substracting Date in java return bad result

Tags: java, date, debugging

Hi I've tried to substract hour from a Date using Date.getTime() - (time in ms ) but the result is not correct , there is always a slight gap compared to the good result, any idea ?

```
if(hoursToBeSubstracted<1) { 
            float toMinute = hoursToBeSubstracted*60;
            return new Date((long)(d1.getTime()-toMinute*60000));
        }
        return new Date((long)(d1.getTime() - 3600 * hoursToBeSubstracted * 1000));
```

Example of output :

```
Before operation Thu Dec 01 13:27:30 CET 2022
Substracting 60.0 minutes
After operation Thu Dec 01 12:28:31 CET 2022
Before operation Wed Nov 30 16:48:52 CET 2022
Substracting 60.0 minutes
After operation Wed Nov 30 15:49:53 CET 2022
Before operation Wed Nov 30 16:48:52 CET 2022
Substracting 60.0 minutes
After operation Wed Nov 30 15:49:53 CET 2022
Before operation Wed Nov 30 16:48:52 CET 2022
Substracting 60.0 minutes
After operation Wed Nov 30 15:49:53 CET 2022
Before operation Thu Dec 01 13:27:30 CET 2022
Substracting 60.0 minutes
After operation Thu Dec 01 12:28:31 CET 2022
```

Comment: Can you show the values you used/expected? I'm interested in this *slight gap*…

Comment: I've added the output

Comment: why did you use `float` ?

Comment: because in the program we must be able to choose how much we want to subtract and it is of the form 1f hour so it can also be 0.1f hour (sry bad english)

Comment: The cleanest way around this is to use the new `java.time` API which provides methods like `minusHours` and so on on `ZonedDateTime` (and other types where it makes sense). The old `java.util.Date` is a terrible API and you should be switching to something saner anyway.

Comment: Try taking a look at this (html tutorial with java time) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gjHmdC-BW0Q2vXiQYmp1rzPU497sybNy/view?usp=share_link

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I have only reproduced approximately. I get `Fri Dec 02 21:43:14 CET 2022` before and `Fri Dec 02 20:44:01 CET 2022` after, so apparently 47 seconds too late where you seem to get 61 seconds too late.

Comment: In `d1.getTime() - 3600 * hoursToBeSubstracted * 1000` you are subtracting a relatively small `float` value from a relatively large one, which gives an inaccurate result. See the linked original question [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### java.time

The `java.time` API, released with Java-8 in March 2014, supplanted the [error-prone legacy date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Since then, it has been strongly recommended to use this modern date-time API.

### Solution using modern date-time API

Convert your `java.util.Date` instance to `java.time.Instant` and subtract hours using [`Instant#minus`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#minus-long-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-).

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date(); // A sample java.util.Date
        Instant instant = date.toInstant();
        Instant updated = instant.minus(3, ChronoUnit.HOURS); // Subtracting 3 hours
        System.out.println(updated);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-12-02T07:13:10.426Z
```

For any reason, if you want to get `java.util.Date` again, you can do so by using [`Date#from`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.